# $f: A \rightarrow C$ and $g: B \rightarrow C$, prove $f \cup g: A \cup B \rightarrow C$ iff $f \restriction (A \cap B) = g \restriction (A \cap B)$

Tags: functions, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

> Suppose $f: A \rightarrow C$ and $g: B \rightarrow C$.
>
> Prove that $f \cup g: A \cup B \rightarrow C$ iff $f \restriction (A \cap B) = g \restriction (A \cap B) $

My attempt:

If I'm getting the definition of the restriction correctly, we have

$$ f \restriction (A \cap B) = f \cap \bigl((A \cap B) \times C\bigr)$$

and

$$ g \restriction (A \cap B) = g \cap \bigl((A \cap B) \times C\bigr)$$

$(\rightarrow)$

Suppose $f \cup g: A \cup B \rightarrow C$

Take $(x,y) \in f \restriction (A \cap B)$. Then $(x,y) \in (A \cap B) \times C$ and $x \in B$.

Since $x \in B$, there exists some $b \in B$ such that $(x,b) \in g$.

Since $(x,b) \in f \cup g$ and $(x,y) \in f \cup g$, we conclude that $y = b$. Hence $(x,y) \in g \restriction A \cap B$, and $f \restriction (A \cap B) \subseteq g \restriction (A \cap B)$.

By the identical reasoning, we can show that $g \restriction (A \cap B) \subseteq f \restriction (A \cap B)$

$(\leftarrow)$

Suppose $f \restriction (A \cap B) = g \restriction (A \cap B)$

Existence: Take $x \in A \cup B$. Then $x \in A$ or $x \in B$, which implies that there exists some $c \in C $ such that either $(x,c) \in f$ or $(x,c) \in g$. Hence $(x,c) \in f \cup g$.

Uniqueness: Suppose $(x,y),(x,p) \in f \cup g$. If both elements are either in $f$ or in $g$, then clearly $y = p$.

Suppose $(x,y) \in f$ and $(x,p) \in g$.

Since $x \in A \cap B$ and $y \in C$, we have $(x,y) \in (A \cap B) \times C$ and therefore $(x,y) \in f \restriction A \cap B$

By the similar reasoning, we have $(x,p) \in g \restriction A \cap B$.

For all $x$ in $Dom(f \restriction A \cap B)$ there is only one $k \in Ran(f \restriction A \cap B)$ such that $(x,k) \in f \restriction A \cap B$

The same reasoning applies to $g \restriction A \cap B$.

Since  $f \restriction (A \cap B) = g \restriction (A \cap B) $, we have $p = y$.

If $(x,p) \in f$ and $(x,y) \in g$, then by the same reasoning, we conclude that $p = y$

We've shown existence and uniqueness, hence the result

$$f \cup g: A \cup B \rightarrow C$$
$\Box$

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Which steps make you uncertain?

Comment: @Berci, thanks for the review. Nothing specific, just wanted to make sure that I haven't missed anything.